# Complete cloud coverage for 300 years

Tags: environment, post-apocalypse, weather, climate-change

What would the weather conditions be like if earth was covered in a layer of clouds and pollution for 300+ years? there is still light in the day but it is minimal and the nights are pitch black.

would the earth cool due to lack of direct sunlight? or would it heat due to  the trapping of heat between the clouds and earth?

Comment: Hi, Aziah97, welcome to Worldbuilding. Your question is tricky. Can you provide more information about the cloud cover and the pollutants? If the clouds and pollutants act as greenhouse gases then global warming will happen. But if they raise the reflectance of the Earth then cooling will occur. More information, please.

Comment: Nights already are "pitch black" (by human standards, anyway) pretty much everywhere below 40-45° latitude or so, and light can be considered "minimal" during the winter months beyond 55-60° latitude or thereabouts. Those two add up to a significant portion of the Earth and its year already. Look up the differences in weather during different parts of the year in those areas; it should provide a starting point. Also keep in mind that even in the countryside, except during pretty much full moon, much night lighting is actually reflected city lights.

Answer (score 3):

The earth would definitely cool down because the clouds are blocking the sun rays from reaching the earths surface. But this means that the surface cannot heat up anymore. For example, think about the carbon cycle. When the earth gets hotter and hotter, more and more water vaporizes and this leads to a emergence of more and denser clouds. Now the clouds are blocking the sun rays. In addition, the more clouds the more rainy days. Now the rain is washing the carbon out of the atmosphere. But this means the earth is cooling down again because the green house effect is reducing due to the decreasing carbon (and as a result the emergence of clouds will slow down and finally the earth will become warmer again). This is an important stabilizing factor. Now imagine, the earth would become hotter due to the clouds. That would lead to a massive self-enhancing process and the earth would just get hotter and hotter.

Answer (score 2):

The Earth would cool to below freezing due to the lack of warming from the sun. Most plants would probably die causing most animals to die off. Small, warm blooded animals such as rats might survive as they will eat nearly anything and need little energy to survive on. Rain fed water would likely become poisonous due to acid rain caused by the pollution. Humans would probably die off en masse although small pockets that had a ground water supply and a renewable,              non-solar generator powering UV lights similair to cannabis growing setups.

It is theorised that a nuclear winter would kill more people than the nuclear war.  Furthermore a winter such as this is likely to have killed off the dinosaurs. So it would probably wipe out the majority of life on earth today.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would cool to a point of winter. Nuclear winters occur quite often in science fiction where dust has been kicked up enough to block the sun, and the result has most frequently been a great cooling, in some cases turning nice lands into tundra. After 300 years only the most resilient flora and fauna would survive.